# git push heroku master error: Repository not found

Tags: heroku, git-push

I just tried pushing to heroku from github and this happened, anyone know how to fix this?

```
$ git push heroku master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside your project folder go into `.git/config` and look at what (if anything) is defined under the `heroku` remote.

For example, one of my apps has:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:jefflunt/cortex.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:cortex-cedar.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku-cedar/*
```

...where `origin` is the github repo, `master` is the master branch on github, and `heroku` is the name and path to the repository on heroku.

It's important that (a) you have an entry for `heroku` because that's what makes your push work, and (b) that it's pointed at the correct path/repo.

To get the path/repo for your project go into you application settings on heroku and it should be listed.

On a side note, these lists of remotes in your `.git/config` file are what make the aliases that you use on the command line work at all, and the names they are given are simply found in the config file.

Comment: running `git remote` lists heroku as a remote (along with origin), and it points to the right git url (which i found on heroku app settings page) - however that still results in `Repository not found`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.git/config` file then? A screenshot of the page where this heroku repo is listed would also be helpful. You're able to push to `origin` without a problem? If we cannot turn up anything from that then it may be time to open a support ticket with heroku.

Answer (score 2):

For the easy solution remove the existing heroku git repo and recreate it.

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and then recreate it

```
heroku create
```

and later if you want to rename

```
heroku rename <name of your app>
```

Comment: This is the solution I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this issue I just deleted this line of code from the .git/config file then I tried repushing to heroku(git push heroku master).

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/dry-bastion-47289.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the Heroku generated app name with our app name in the [remote "heroku"] section of the config file

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/[your_app_name].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```